# Can HTMLUnit package be used with PhantomJsDriver.java

Tags: phantomjs, htmlunit

I am using "org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJsDriver" Java class.

At times, I need to identify whether a given WebElement is a particular type of web element; eg: Is this webelement a input type element or not.
This does not seem to come with PhantomJsDriver package.

"com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit." package seems to have useful wrappers on top of web elements. I can write code like "element instanceof HtmlInput".

Question here is
- Can I really HTMLunit package with phantomjsdriver ? Am I using two libraries which are not supposed to be used with one-another ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately, you can't do this the way you're doing it. `PhantomJsDriver` is backed by WebKit, while `HtmlUnitDriver` is backed by HtmlUnit which has its own browser core. Selenium is able to wrap both these (and some more) under one hood, but we can't use them interchangeably.

There are, however, different ways of doing what you're trying to do, the best probably being using Selenium's own methods [`getTagName()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getTagName%28%29) and [`getAttribute()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) if needed.

If you ran `getTagName()` on your input element, it would gladly return `"input"`.